# Forçar usuário selecionar o Radio Button dentro do GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como faço para forçar usuário selecionar um Radio Button dentro do GroupBox.

Exemplo da imagem abaixo

[image: Imagem1]

Comment: Não poderia colocar um pré selecionado?

Comment: Seria interessante também, mas se houvesse a possibilidade de jogar um alerta caso o usuario esquecesse.

Comment: @DanilloVictor Minha resposta resolveu seu problema? Se sim, considere marca-la como aceita.

Comment: Pronto, marcado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando `LINQ` pode ficar assim:

```
using System.Linq;

// gbRadioButtons - Nome do seu groupBox que contém os radio buttons.        
var anySelected = gbRadioButtons.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x => x.Checked);

if(!anySelected) // Se nenhum foi selecionado
{
   MessageBox.Show("Por favor, selecione um item.");
}
```

No código acima, estou usando `LINQ` para iterar sobre todos os itens do tipo `RadioButton` dentro do seu `GroupBox` e busco se pelo menos algum `RadioButton` foi selecionado e gravo este valor na variável `anySelected`.

Comment: Poderia colocar direto `if(!gbRadioButtons.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x => x.Checked))`, não poderia?.

Comment: Considerei isto, mas resolvi colocar numa variável separada para organizar melhor o exemplo e manter ele mais legível.

Comment: Fica bem mais legível do jeito que fez mesmo.