# Verificar Se campo do DataGridView do tipo DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn está marcado

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um dataGridView e faço a verificação para saber se na coluna do tipo DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn tem alguma linha selecionado. Se houver pelo menos uma linha com este campo selecionado executo um tipo de ação, senão disparo uma mensagem do tipo Messabox.

```
Int32 verificaCheckBoxGrid = 0;

//varrendo o dataGridView
for (Int32 index = 0; index < meuDataGridView.Rows.Count; index++) {
  // verifica se pelo menos 1 checkbox do grid esta ativado
  if (bool.Parse(meuDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()) == true) {
    verificaCheckBoxGrid++;
  }
}

// se não conter pelo menos 1 checkbox ativado no dataGridView
if (verificaCheckBoxGrid < 1 || meuDataGridView.Rows.Count == 0) {
  MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma Nota Selecionada", "A T E N Ç Ã O", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  return;
}
```

Gostaria de fazer algo que ficasse com o código mais apresentável como por exemplo neste caso abaixo que é verificado se algum dos radiobutton's que estão em um grupoBox tem pelo menos um selecionado, [conforme esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243599/for%C3%A7ar-usu%C3%A1rio-selecionar-o-radio-button-dentro-do-groupbox).

```
// usando LINQ -  verifica se todos os checkbox dentro do grupo box estão desmarcados
if (!gbTipoDePagamento.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x => x.Checked)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Selecione Um Tipo De Pagamento", "A T E N Ç Ã O", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  return;
}
```

Como saber se tem algo do tipo:

```
if (!nomeDoDataGridView.Controls.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn>().Any(x => x.Checked))
```

Comment: Você está utilizando  algum Model de dados   em seu DataGrid?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um método de extensão para as `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, assim você pode usar de uma forma mais simples:

**Método:**

```
public static List<DataGridViewRow> CheckedRows(this DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn c)
{
    return c.DataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells[c.Name].Value != null && (bool)r.Cells[c.Name].Value).ToList();
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var linhas = minhaCheckBoxColumn.CheckedRows();

    if (linhas.Count > 0)
    {
        //há linhas marcadas
    }
}
```

> Preferi retornar uma lista de `DataGridViewRow` para que o método possa ser utilizado de forma mais ampla.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver usando um itemSoucer(model) para preencher o seu DataGridView você pode colocar um Biding para um determinado campo que no caso seria seu Checkbox

dentro do seu model crie um novo elemento chamado MARCADO e faça as verificações
No seu  model  pode colocar algo  parecido com isso

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
 public bool MARCADO { get; set; }
```

E para veirficar os campos marcados utilize esse codigo abaixo

```
// verifica se todos estão  marcados  
bool a = dgv.Controls.OfType<SeuModel>().All(x => x.MARCADO == true);

// verifica se todos estão  marcados desmarcados 
bool b = dgv.Controls.OfType<SeuModel>().All(x => x.MARCADO == false);

// verifica se tem  algum marcado
int c = dgv.Controls.OfType<SeuModel>().Where(x => x.MARCADO == false).Count();
```

O `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped` serve para ignorar o mapeamento caso esteja usando Entity no seu projeto.

para mais detalhes [veja esse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278508/wpf-selecionar-todos-os-checkbox-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma mais simples e talvez mais elegante seja:

```
var existeCheckBoxMarcado = MeuDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].FormattedValue));

if (!existeCheckBoxMarcado)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma Nota Selecionada", "A T E N Ç Ã O", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```