# WPF selecionar todos os CheckBox DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Olá, estou  tentando  selecionar todos os CheckBox de um datagrid porem não estou obtendo êxito.

Abaixo está meu código para selecionar:

```
private void CheckUnCheckAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkSelectAll = ((CheckBox)sender);
    if (chkSelectAll.IsChecked == true)
    {
        dgUsers.Items.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = true);
    }
    else
    {       
         dgUsers.Items.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = false);
    }
}
```

A onde `dgUsers` é meu DataGrid porem pude notar que não está encontrando nenhum checkbox dentro do grid.

Abaixo está meu xaml a onde cria o  checkbox dentro do datagrid veja que eu invoco a função ao clicar no checkbox:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="col0" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}">
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <CheckBox Click="CheckUnCheckAll" >
                   </CheckBox>
              </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

Aqui tem uma  imagem do grid

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a forma correta para selecionar todos os CheckBox de um Datagrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ago assim que você procura ?

```
//this event is for **Checked and UnChecked** of up check box (cbxall)
private void UpCheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //checkBox1 = cbxall (your up checkbox)
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = true);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = false);
    }
}

//this event is for all other check box
//**Checked and UnChecked** of all other check box is this event
private void OtherCheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //checkBox1 = cbxall (your up checkbox)
    if (dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().All(x => x.IsChecked == true))
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if (dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().All(x => x.IsChecked == false))
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = null;
    }
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208004/datagrid-column-header-should-check-uncheck-checkbox-s-state-depending-upon-wh)

Comment: ou o  elemento que quero No caso CheckBox ?

Comment: se não me engano CheckBox, se você verificar o código é parecido com o que já tens atualmente é só adaptar

Comment: Obrigado depois de uma pesquisa descobrir que a onde está p  YourClass é o ModelView que deve ser passado e o isChecked é  o  nome da propriedade que está definida no modelview para o biding do checkbox